# How to validate Select element using ReactiveFormModule in angularJS2?

Tags: validation, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I want to validate my form using ReactiveFormModule in angularJS2, Suppose I have a Component code like this

```
export class userComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
    userForm: FormGroup;
    users = new userDetails();
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.buildForm();
    }

    buildForm(): void {
        this.userForm = this.fb.group({
            'qualification': [this.users.qualification, Validators.required]
        });

        this.userForm.valueChanges
            .subscribe(data => this.onValueChanged(data));

        this.onValueChanged(); // (re)set validation messages now
    }
    onValueChanged(data?: any) {
        debugger;
        if (!this.userForm) { return; }
        const form = this.userForm;

        for (const field in this.formErrors) {
            // clear previous error message (if any)
            this.formErrors[field] = '';
            const control = form.get(field);

            if (control && control.dirty && !control.valid) {
                const messages = this.validationMessages[field];
                for (const key in control.errors) {
                    this.formErrors[field] += messages[key] + ' ';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    onSubmit() {
        this.users = this.userForm.value;
    }
    formErrors = {
        'designation':''
    };

    validationMessages = {
        'designation': {
            'required':'Please select a designation.'
        }
    };
}
```

And I have a HTML code like this

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="designation" required>
                                <option selected>Select Designation</option>
                                <optgroup label="Accounts">
                                    <option>Trainee</option>
                                    <option>Junior Accountant</option>
                                    <option>Senior Accountant</option>
                                </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="Sales">
                                    <option>Sales Executive</option>
                                    <option>Sales Regional Manager</option>
                                    <option>Sales Manager</option>
                                </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="IT">
                                    <option>Junior Software Developer</option>
                                    <option>Senior Software Developerr</option>
                                    <option>Tech Lead</option>
                                    <option>Project Lead</option>
                                    <option>Project Manager</option>
                                    <option>Manager</option>
                                </optgroup>
                            </select>
```

There is no article, which actually explains on how to validate select button in angularJS2, can we actually validate the select element using angularJS2?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same problem's solution but there isn't any useful help anywhere. So, for future ref,

Select Inputs only need `required` validation (afaik) and that only needs to trigger on `submit` event.

Keeping these things in mind I came up with following solution.

1. Initialize select values to null (not empty string " ")
2. Check if the input/select is invalid
3. Mark input/select as touched
4. Set Value to empty string " "

with following code:

```
validateFormOnSubmit(rootFormGroup: FormGroup){
        Object.keys(rootFormGroup.controls).map((controlName: string) => {
            rootFormGroup.get(controlName).markAsTouched();
            if (rootFormGroup.get(controlName).invalid){
                rootFormGroup.get(controlName).setValue("");
            }
        });
}
```

then you can simply validate on changed value something like this:

```
rootFormGroup.get(controlName).valueChanges.subscribe((value)=>{
   console.log('change detected')
}
```